# Special characters not working in Firestore string

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pull some data from a website to my Firebase Firestore database, but I got a small problem with special characters being converted to weird characters, for example this phrase "he’s good at – finding people." is converted to this one "heâ€™s good at â€“ finding people.", do I have to escape those characters or what?

Code:

```
String url =
      'some-url';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  String body = response.body;
  List results = jsonDecode(body)['results'];
 await firestore
            .collection('games')
            .document(results[i]['id'].toString())
            .setData({
          'description': results[i]['description']});
```

Comment: What encoding is your text following?

Comment: don't know just the default.

Comment: Can you show minimum reproducible code? Firestore uses UTF-8 so in most scenarios there shouldn't be an issue. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: updated the question with the code

Comment: add a console log after setting `results` (after 5th line in above code) and share the results

Comment: Firestore doesn't have any requirements for encoding.  Strings should go in and out exactly as you specify without any trouble.

Comment: Maybe I have to specify the decoding type in jsondecode function. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just used utf8 to decode the result string,

```
utf8.decode(results[i]['description'].toString().runes.toList());
```

Thanks for help.